# Pass Any Method (not just Action or Func) as a Parameter

Tags: methods, delegates

In C#, I wanted to know how would you pass a method, any method, as a parameter?

I know about Action and Func, but those are limited by methods either being void in the former or needing to return a value in the latter.  I would like to include support for both cases, if possible (I may have a param array of methods).

I presume some use of delegate is involved, but I'm not sure how (with and without lambdas).  Thanks!

something like...

```
public void DoSomething(int num)
{...}

public void DoSomethingElse()
{...}

public int ReturnSomething(string str, int num)
{...}

public void RunMethods(params object[] methods) // (params delegate[] methods)?
{
    foreach(var method in methods)
    {
        ...determine whether its void or not and run.
    }
}

RunMethod(DoSomething, ReturnSomething, DoSomethingElse);

...
```

Comment: Methods cannot be passed -- they are *not* first-class constructs. However, `Method1(Method2)` will work as the compiler will "lift" the method-group `Method2` if there is a[n implicit] conversion possible. (I think to a `delegate`, but the details of the magic escapes me.)

Comment: As to support both `Func<X,R>` and `Action<X>` in the past I have created an overload; the overload that takes in the `Action` simply wraps the `Func` overload putting the Action in a stub-Function and discarding the return (to void). I am not sure if this is ideal, but it has worked for me... another option is to only take `Func<X,R>` and return `default(R)`...